# How to get Sundays and Saturdays in month in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In 'hr.payslip' I need to calculate number of Sat&Sun in selected month.Based on that will get number of working in particular month.

Comment: you will get the saturdays and sundays from attendence record right/ in workshedule

Comment: What is the actual need and kindly post your rule to achieve

Comment: I needed how many Sundays and Saturdays in month. Because of calculate  number of working days in a month

Comment: you can try total workng days - total days gives the off days right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example:

```
     @api.one
     def get_day(self):

        fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
        d1 = datetime.strptime("2016-12-31", fmt)
        d2 = datetime.strptime("2017-01-30", fmt)

        SatAndSun = 0

        dates_btwn = d1
        while dates_btwn <= d2:    
            dates_btwn = dates_btwn + timedelta(days=1)
            if(dates_btwn.strftime("%A") == "Saturday"):
                SatAndSun += 1
            elif(dates_btwn.strftime("%A") == "Sunday"):
                SatAndSun += 1
            else:
                SatAndSun += 0
        print(SatAndSun)  #return 9 days
```

In my example for month January I use one day before! from 31.12.2016 to 30.01.2017